# R extracting elements from list (coerced from PDF) that has multiple elements but says the length of the list is only 1?

Tags: r, list

I'm attempting to read a PDF into R by brute forcing it to read the text and then trying to convert that text into a data frame. I feel like I'm close this is what I have at the moment. This is a small subset of the full list:

```
> testlist

    [[1]]                             
     [1] "A 2% 14,000.00 1,000.00 3.98 46.33 0.00 6.33 40.32 186.02\r"
     [2] "B 300% 1,000.00 17.70 0.00 0.00 0.00 52,987.30 0.00 91,736.00\r"
```

The actual list runs 35 elements this is just a subset. 
The problem I'm having is that this list shows as having length of only 1, and I have no idea how to get these elements out of this list. Subsetting the list doesn't work, is there a smart way to extract each row from this list as it's own unique character? So I'd like to be able create variables for each row like so:

```
a = "A 2% 14,000.00 1,000.00 3.98 46.33 0.00 6.33 40.32 186.02\r"
b = "B 300% 1,000.00 17.70 0.00 0.00 0.00 52,987.30 0.00 91,736.00\r"
```

From there I could attack it using gsub or something similar, but I can't figure out how to actually extract each "row" from the list since it says the entire list is actually of length 1. I'm also curious, what are the numbers off to the left hand side of when the list displays? The [1] and the [2]? They look like numbers for rows, but this is a list and they can't be elements of the list since it says the list only contains 1 element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` to extract the elements as a `vector`.  The `[1]`, `[2]` are just `vector` elements in the `list` of `length` 1.

```
v1 <- testlist[[1]]
```

Or if the `list` is of length greater than 1, use `unlist`

```
v1 <- unlist(testlist)
```

---

It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global env, but if it is really needed

```
list2env(setNames(as.list(v1), c('a', 'b')), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Unlist worked! The first method for some reason didn't, testlist[[1]] returned the entire list, but unlist seems to have split it apart into a character? I'm incredible confused why this worked, but it looks like I might have what I need. Can I ask you what those numbers represented on the left side of my list? So they are vector elements, but what does that mean? Does the list treat them as vectors that are all 1 element? I guess I'm just confused why it can have multiple vector elements but still have length of only 1?

Comment: @JedBartlet From what you showed, it seems like `testlist` is a list of length 1.  So, `testlist[[1]]` should extract that `list` element into a `vector` i.e. it is similar to `l1 <- list(c(5, 3, 2)); l1[[1]]`  Only difference is that because the element character length is greater, the print method prints it on a new line with `[1]`, `[2]`

Comment: I think I see what you mean testlist[[1]][1]did get me just the first element, so I have to subset it twice that works, perfect. I'm still mad confused, but at least now I know the right terminology. So this was a list of length 1, but that had multiple vector elements? I wasn't even sure what to google, but at least now I can google the correct terms.

Comment: @JedBartlet  Yes, you have a `list` of length 1 with `vector` as its elements and the `vector` length is 2.  YOu don't have to do multiple subsetting i.e. `v1 <-  testlist[[1]]` do the assignment to an object and then extract if needed,, but why create multiple objects ?

Comment: that was for testing purposes, I will have to loop through each element, I actually need to convert each vector element into a column, which I'm not sure but I'm subsetting them like that to create v1, v2 etc. to figure out how to convert them into columns for a dataframe

Comment: @JedBartlet If you need columns of a data.frame, either do `as.data.frame(t(testlist[[1]]))` or `as.data.frame.list(testlist[[1]])`